# Синхронизация MSsql и oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Задача: 2 базы данных Mssql 2000 и oracle должны синхронизироваться через 3й компьютер под управление ubuntu 16.04.
Какие существуют способы(Скрипты, ПО и т.д.)

Comment: Если сможете предоставить больше деталей по задаче - постараюсь предоставить больше информации по возможностям синхронизации

Answer (score 0):

Из бесплатного ПО можно попробовать использовать ETL инструменты:

1. [Talend Open Studio for Data Integration](https://www.talend.com/download/talend-open-studio)
2. [Pentaho Data Integration - Kettle](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/)

Но надо понимать, что добиться real-time интеграции с их использованием будет сложно.